# Усовершенствовать регулярное выражение

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Сделал регулярку `^[0-9]{2}|_{2}|[0-9]_|_[0-9]$`, ее задача отловить два знака типа: "две цифры ЛИБО два _(нижний символ подчеркивания) ЛИБО одна цифра и один _ ЛИБО один _ и одна цифра". Регулярка рабочая, но я в ней тупо перечислил комбинации. А если мне потребуется не два знака отслеживать а допустим четыре? Как мне скомпоновать выражение без перечисления комбинаций?

Comment: так как у тебя все комбинации перебираются вполне можно сократить до `^[0-9_]{2}$` - два любых символа из набора

Answer (score 0):

> Регулярка рабочая

Нет:

```js
console.log(/^[0-9]{2}|_{2}|[0-9]_|_[0-9]$/.test("Ты скобки забыл o_0"))
```

> Как мне скомпоновать выражение без перечисления комбинаций?

```
^[0-9_]{2}$
```